# For faculty hiring, if the committee requests my references to provide letters (after an interview), can I assume that I am short-listed?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

I did an on campus interview, after 2 weeks the department chair emailed me that “We are in final stages of our decision and have requested your references to provide letters. If possible, please prompt them to provide them at their earliest convenience.”

Usually I have communicated with the committee chair during interview processes, but the department chair contacted me this time. Can I assume that I am a top candidate from this email?

Comment: It's likely. Do get your references to respond soon.

Answer (score 6):

You can conclude that you are among a small group among which a final decision will (likely) be made, but no more. Don't get complacent at this time and get those letters out.

Rarely, all candidates are rejected, however, and the process starts over. Nothing is certain until it happens. Good luck.